# Amazon S3 : Redirect rule to API gateway not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Following the [Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/), I've setup a redirect for my S3 bucket, but when a non-existing object is requested, gives same AccessDenied error. The bucket and Lambda function are in the same region. What am I doing wrong?

I test API Gateway endpoint also, it's working either.

```
https://7ee55x3dz3.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/api
```

Here is S3 Redirect Rule

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals/>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <Protocol>https</Protocol>
        <HostName>7ee55x3dz3.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>prod/api?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I also tried with 404.

Comment: Are you using the correct *website hosting endpoint* to access the bucket?  If the error is XML, you are not.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot there is not website hosting endpoint in xml to access bucket. This xml is added in bucket redirection rules

Comment: I'm quite familiar with redirection rules, so let's try this again: when you access the bucket, you see an error message.  That error message is either displayed as XML or HTML.  Please specify which, or show the actual error.

Comment: I get This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>

Comment: In the bucket settings, under static web site hosting, you will find the correct endpoint hostname to use when accessing the bucket.  The fact that your error messages are displaying as XML indicates that this is not how you are currently accessing the bucket.

Comment: but i am not accessing bucket anywhere. I want to redirect to API Gateway in case 404 or 403

Comment: Yes, you are: *"when a non-existing object is requested"* ...please provide an example URL.

Comment: I get your point regarding correct endpoint hostname. You can give that in answer

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot can we post image also on static website hosting?